# Error when computing Cosine Similarity

Tags: distance, similarities, regression-coefficients, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to compute the cosine similarity of the following vector:

```
1 1 0 1
2 0 1 1
```

$$ \frac {1*2+1*0+0*1+1*1}{ \sqrt{1^2+1^2+0^2+1^2}\sqrt{2^2+0^2+1^2+1^2}} \,\,.$$

According to Wolframalpha this is equal to:

$$\frac{3}{1.732 * 2.449} = 0.707 \,\,.$$

But according to this document [Example for computing cosine
similarity](https://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/suppl/2009/10/24/btp613.DC1/bioinf-2008-1835-File004.pdf) (where I have the upper equation from) the result is 
$0.72$.

Who is wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything off topic in asking how to calculate cosine similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in R this is

```
v1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1)
v2 = c(2, 0, 1, 1)
sum(v1 * v2) / sqrt(sum(v1^2) * sum(v2^2))
## 0.7071
```

Second, by hand you can find that this is exactly equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ which is approximately 0.707. So Wolfram Alpha is correct. The pdf might have rounded strangely or made an arithmetic error.